# What is a coalesce stage in Bigquery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Want to understand what is the coalesce stage in `Bigquery` and in what cases this stage is seen in the plan. I didn't found information about this stage in `bigquery` documentation.

**Note:** I am not using coalesce function in the query.

Following is the screenshot for reference
[image]

Comment: Is your external_xxx table a BigQuery native table or an external table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `coalesce` step in the query plan is because you are querying multiple tables. This step is combining the data from each additional table you query. So, each new table, a new `coalesce` (and `join`) will be added to combine this data.

Its different than the conditional function [COALESCE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#:%7E:text=COALESCE(%3Cexpr1%3E%2C%20%3Cexpr2%3E%2C%20...))

---

The point is, each step can directly write only one set of data to a next step. If a new set have to write, this data will be read again, that will be the coalesce step. The following chart represents what happen when 1, 2 or 3 tables a queried, and shows the join and coalesce steps. This is just an exemplification, another operations as cross are been omitted.

[image]

Comment: @ewertonsilva Thanks for you quick response so if coalesce is used for combining the data then what is the use of join. Can you please add some more light on this

Comment: Hi @SachinJanani, no problem. I have added more information in he answer, I think it will clarify the query plan for you.

Comment: When i do inner join between 2 tables then i dont see the coalesce stage? @eweronsilva can you please explain that

Comment: hi @SachinJanani, in this case, the step_0 will read one of the tables and write to next step. In the next step (output) the second table will be read and data compared. As each one of the tables in read in a different step, and only one table is write to the next step (step_0 -> output), there is no need to read again one of the tables, so no coalesce needed. If you Have further questions related to another query types, Please create a new question in order to not mix the subjects and keeping questions helpful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

You will also see the coalesce on INSERT operations, usually with low consumption and low wait and low write times